# How to evaluate variable as binary expression in bash script

Tags: bash, if-statement

while doing some bash scripting I ran into a situation in which I wasn't really sure how to do something. How do I evaluate the entire contents of a string as a single expression inside of single if statement expression.

```
expression="0 != 1"
if [[ $expression ]]; then
     eval $action
     exit $?
fi
```

Comment: Why do you want to? It'll take some unnatural contorting. Perhaps there's a better way to accomplish your [underlying goal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: I want it so that I can have a user defined action and condition.

Comment: Remember `eval` is only a single vowel away from `evil`...

Comment: A user defined action and condition, what does that mean? Could you give an example? This smells strongly of an XY problem.

Comment: User defines a condition and then the command that the user defined runs if the condition evaluates as True.

Comment: What's a concrete example?

Comment: Service reads in and parses a config file.  While running the service, during a particular point of interest, the user wants a certain command run because of a certain condition that was met.  Impossible to know before hand, as a developer, how or what user will want to run or the condition the user will want to check, hence the reason it is user defined.
Example: Service detected a new file, user has a custom action he would like ran on the file.

Comment: Why read it from the config file as a string, rather than as a function?

Comment: That is, if you trust your config files to contain code, go all the way and make it `expression() { [[ 0 != 1; ]]; }` and then `if expression; then` -- that way, the user can put whatever they want in there, and you aren't playing games with string-splitting that restrict the input domain.

Comment: ...the `expression='...'` approach doesn't work in the general case; it runs into the problems discussed in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), and limitations in `[` not present in `[[`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the old style single brackets, because `[[` does not do word splitting of variables.

`[` is a normal command, so variable expansion happens normally.

```
if [ $expression ]; then
```

Alternatively, you can use `eval` in the `if` condition:

```
if eval "[[ $expression ]]"; then
```

Comment: or fall back to `test`: `if test $expression; then`

Comment: That's the same as `[`, I see no value in using that name.